# Need to integrate JBoss 7.1.1 to MyEclipse 8.6 how can i do it?

Tags: jboss7.x, myeclipse

Need to integrate JBoss 7.1.1 to MyEclipse 8.5 any ideas how can i doit cause i can't see JBoss 7.x.x for this MyEclipse version. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the connector for an earlier release of JBoss and see if that works (just specify the install location for JBoss 7.1.

For full support, you'd be better off moving to the latest release of MyEclipse (2013). A MyEclipse license is not based on the release, so you can install any release during the period of your license.